# Absolute Column Reference in Excel Table

Tags: microsoft-excel

Using the below formula I can lock in the position of column `C:C`, by pressing `F4` to include `$`s, and leaving `F9` free to move when the cell is dragged across.

```
  =COUNTIFS('PCC - SQL'!$C:$C,Summary!F9)
```

So when I drag it across it become:

```
=COUNTIFS('PCC - SQL'!$C:$C,Summary!G9)
```

How do I achieve this with table references ?

I have this as my formula:

```
=COUNTIFS(Query1[[#All],[Accounting_Period]],Summary!E9)
```

And want to lock the `[Accounting_Period]` so when I drag across I don't get the `[Customer_Number]`, like below:

```
=COUNTIFS(Query1[[#All],[CUSTOMER_NUMBER]],Summary!F9)
```

Comment: I've always wondered this myself. I don't think you can anchor ($) the table column. I've just went into the cell and highlighted the text and copied to the next cell, then changed the F to G...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need `[#All]` in your formula and as you only have 1 condition in your formula, `COUNTIF` will suffice.

You need to double up the table references with a colon between them.  So:

`=COUNTIFS(Query1[[#All],[Accounting_Period]],Summary!E9)`

should become:

```
=COUNTIF(Query1[[Accounting_Period]:[Accounting_Period]],Summary!E9)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may make the name "absolute" by using an `INDIRECT` reference to the column, but the drawback is that if you rename the column it will not change the indirect reference:

```
=COUNTIFS(INDIRECT("Query1[Accounting_Period]"),Summary!E9)
```

So each solution has one advantage and one drawback, the good point is that you have now the choice between the two solutions.